# avoid race condition using sunchronized block in different methods on same resource

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition, synchronized

I'm writing a simple crawler that saves a specified number of pages starting from root URL.
It traverses links using BFS approach.
Here is class code:

```
    public class SimpleCrawler implements Runnable {

    private int maxPages;
    private List<String> visitedPages;
    private List<String> linksToVisit;
    private File saveDir;
    private int linksOnPage;

    public SimpleCrawler(String rootUrl, File saveDir, List<String> visitedPages, int maxPages, int linksOnPage) {
        linksToVisit = new ArrayList<>();
        linksToVisit.add(rootUrl);
        this.saveDir = saveDir;
        this.visitedPages = visitedPages;
        this.maxPages = maxPages;
        this.linksOnPage = linksOnPage;
    }

    private boolean addUrl(String url) {
        synchronized (visitedPages) {
            return visitedPages.add(url);
        }
    }

    private boolean deleteUrl(String url) {
        synchronized (visitedPages) {
            return visitedPages.remove(url);
        }
    }

    private int getListSize(){
        synchronized (visitedPages){
            return visitedPages.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (getListSize() < maxPages) {
            String url = linksToVisit.remove(0);
            if (!visitedPages.contains(url)) {
                this.addUrl(url);
            }

            // do my staff
        }
    }
}
```

I have some methods each of them capture monitor of shared list and releases after work is done.
I think that locking and unlocking of shared list may cause such situation:

```
maxPages = 100

Thread1 getListSize() < 100;// listSize = 99
...
Thread2 getListSize() < 100;// listSize = 99
...
Thread1 addUrl(url);// listSize = 100
...
Thread2 addUrl(url);// listSize = 101 while maxPages = 100
```

Can second thread check size before first thread releases monitor?
    or
Is it better to combine these two actions in one critical section?

Comment: I think you might find it easier using concurrent queues, like `BlockingQueue`. These are designed for such applications.

Comment: As you've realised, all read+write operations on the list need to be handled atomically and so occur within a synchronized block, i.e. the getListSize() and addUrl() both need to occur in the same synchronized block.

Comment: I'd also make the backing list private to this class and handle all operations in there to prevent clients accidentally operating without synchronized control.

Comment: Thank for your suggestions, I've got my mistake.